# "I found it a strain having to concentrate for so long." Why does this sentence use 'having'?

Tags: dummy-it, gerund-phrases, extraposition

I read below sentence.

> I found it a strain **having** to concentrate for so long.

I guess this sentence means 'I got pressure that I can't give all my attention for long hours'.

My question is why there is 'having'? Does it imply 'have to concentrate'(indicating meaning of obligation) or 'have concentrated'(indicating present perfect)?

Comment: “I got pressure that I can’t give all my attention for long hours” is not idiomatic English; no native speaker would ever say that. There is a fundamental difference between _have to_ + infinitive and _have_ + past participle. This difference remains the same regardless of what form of the verb _have_ is used: it’s what follows (past participle vs. _to_ + infinitive) that makes a difference. As such, I can see no way to understand _having to concentrate_ as indicating the perfect aspect.

Answer (score 2):

> 'have to concentrate'(indicating meaning of obligation)

I would say yes obligation.

> I found it a strain having to concentrate for so long in that exam.

that makes it much more obvious doesn't it.